# How to determine if a result is random variation or an unusual event

Tags: statistics

Question is: over the period of 27 years an average of 81 new cases of cancer was diagnosed per year. For the 28th year the count was 108 new cancer patients, do appropriate calculations to determine if this is random fluctuation or an unusual event

Comment: Do you know anything about the distribution of number of new cases per year over the period of 27 years?

Comment: This needs clarification.  If, every year, the number is either 82 or 80 (averaging to 81) then 108 would be shocking.  On the other hand, if every year, the number was either 110 or 50, also averaging to around 81, then 108 would look like random fluctuation.

Answer (score 3):

You can't "determine" if this is random fluctuation, but you can say something about how unlikely it is to see this kind of result in a model.

Hopefully we're talking about a reasonably large and stable population here; the probability for any given individual to get a new cancer in a given year is small, and occurrences in different individuals are independent.  Then it's reasonable to model the number $X$ of new cases in any year as a Poisson random variable, with parameter $\lambda = 81$ (the mean value).  For such a 
distribution, the probability of $X \ge 108$ would be  approximately
$0.0024$, which seems quite small.  On the other hand, in $28$ years the probability of having at least one year with at least $108$ cases is
about $0.0651$, which is not so small that you can discount random fluctuation.

Again, you can't be sure one way or the other: I would think it's suspicious enough that further investigation might be a good idea, but you certainly haven't ruled out random fluctuation.

Comment: The speed of these responses is remarkable I'm in awe. The question was vague to begin with. Robert you seemed to have given me enough to work with. I'll re-write the question below.

Comment: In a certain population over the years 1975-2002 an average of 81 new cases of rectal cancer are diagnosed each year. There appears no upward or downward trend over time in the number of cases. In 2003 the number of cases was 104 (108 in my example). Perform appropriate calculations to decide whether this should be considered a random fluctuation or an unusual event.